# Unable to publish a update version of the android application

Tags: android, google-play

The update version of the Application is successfully uploaded to play store for Alpha testing. But while i am publishing the same update, Play store Rejecting the application and showing violation of the **Malicious behavior** policy.The Application was working fine previously. I have changed a audio and a image file in the project.There are no changes in the previous code so far.I am unable to figure out the issue

Please help.

Comment: That sounds like something you should bring up with [the Google Play support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/3453554?hl=en&ref_topic=2364761).

Comment: you need to change the versionCode and versionName in your manifest file or in the build.gradle file.

Comment: I have changed the versionCode and versionName in the build.gradle file.

Comment: I have changed the versionCode and versionName in the build.gradle file. But the issue still exist.

Comment: Most likely your app has a security vulnerability. The message should have told you what the vulnerability was and how to fix it.

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-and-security.html#malicious-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at below link.
[Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).
You should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value for the android:versionCode.You also need to change the android:versionName value as per my knowledge in each of your new releases.
You define both of these version attributes(android:versionCode,android:versionName) in the `<manifest>` element of the manifest file or the Gradle build file.
If this doesn't solve your problem you please go through this link 
[Your app was rejected for violating Google’s policy](http://www.androidb.com/2015/11/your-app-was-rejected-for-violating-googles-policy-now-what/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have changed the versionCode and versionName of the project and cleaned the application. Then i signed the application and uploaded to play store. But when publishing the app to the alpha, the result was same.

Comment: Read this document  http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have used any library which is already embedded in framework code. For ex: json.jar etc.